# Binary to decimal without using math.pow in java

Tags: java

So I am asked to write a program that converts a binary number to a decimal. In that case it's 10111. The problem that I have is that I am not allowed to use math.pow, so I have to use a nested loop. This is what I have so far.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 10111;

        int num = 0, counter = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i *= 10) {

            int binaryDigit = x/i%10;
            num += (int) (Math.pow(2, counter) * binaryDigit);
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.println("\""+ x + "\" in binary is equivalent to " + num + " in decimal");
    }
```

Comment: you can also do it by multiplying loop.2 power 5 =2*2*2*2*2

Comment: @luk2302 the code works but my problem was that I wanted to replace the math.pow thing with a loop.

Comment: @FastSnail Indeed. As the loop in the question's code starts with the least-significant digit, the power can actually be calculated within the same loop. (as done in my answer)

Comment: A very slow, bad and lazy solution: `num = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(x), 2);`. The used Libraries don't use `Math.pow()`, but i'm not sure, if you are allowed to use them. Otherwise you could write a pow() function yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could double the value of the current digit position as you go through the binary digits in your loop.
That way you have the pow value you need already available in each step.
1,2,4,8,16,...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 10111;

    int num = 0;

    int digitval = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i *= 10) {

        int binaryDigit = x/i%10;
        num += digitval * binaryDigit;
        digitval *= 2;
    }
    System.out.println("\""+ x + "\" in binary is equivalent to " + num + " in decimal");
}
```

Comment: This was the method I was looking for. Since I am taking an introduction to java programming. I am only allowed to use the basic methods you described. I ran the code and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can compute a power of two in Java using bit shifting.

Observe that `1` is 2<sup>0</sup>. Also observe that adding `k` zeros to the right of `1` in binary notation produces `k`-th power of 2, for the same reason that adding zeros in decimal notation multiplies the number by ten.

Therefore, you can replace the call to `Math.pow` with this simple expression:

```
num += (1 << counter) * binaryDigit;
```

**Note:** Representing binary number as a decimal number composed of only 1s and 0s has an inconvenient limitation: you cannot represent numbers above 1023, because you run out of decimal digits. A more convenient representation would be a `String`.

Comment: I would intensify your answer: Unless you are already working with floating point values (`float` `double`) you should **never ever use** `Math.pow()`!.

Comment: @Robert I don't know about "never", that's too strong a statement, but I would agree that casting `Math.pow` to `int` is a very strong sign that you should look for a better alternative to doing the same thing.

Comment: This method works but I'm sorry my instructor does not allow me to use it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will do the trick

```
int binaryNumber = x;
int power = 0;
int result = 0;
while (binaryNumber / 10 > 0) {
//lets start the loop and parse the length of the binary number
int digit = binaryNumber % 10;
result += digit << power;
power++;
binaryNumber = binaryNumber/10;
}
```